# ChromeDriver 114 Login failure

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, automation, webdriver

I'm using Java selenium to test my application , I have opened my application and logged in successfully .on the second iteration I'm reopening the browser and launching the same url , it asks the login again ? Is there any recent issues on chromedriver 113 and 114

Same flow is working fine in default profile .